# how to make existing flash file responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flash

I have e learning books in flash file(.swf format) and i want to make it responsive.Can any one suggest a solution for this.please refer the link [flash file](http://rtpublishers.com/data/Hindi/Book1/example1.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you open the raw swf files in a browser, you can see that they are already responsive by default: http://rtpublishers.com/data/Hindi/Book1/pages/page1.swf

So, you need to change the way the Flash is embedded in your html page. Where you are using fixed 1300 x 900 pixels dimensions, use percentages instead.

In your Flash file, you can set the stage scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT as explained here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS0D75B487-23B9-402d-A52D-CB3C4CEB9EE4.html
If there are parts of the Flash that you want to scale differently depending on stage size, you can listen to the stage RESIZE event, and respond accordingly.